# If $y=f(x)$ is increasing on $X$ then is $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ always decreasing on X?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $y=f(x)$ is increasing on $X$ then is $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ always decreasing on X?

Help I have to prove this without calculus!

Answer (score 9):

The claim is not true in general. Consider $X=\Bbb R$ and  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x<0\\x+1&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$$
This is an increasing function. However, the reciprocal is 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x&\text{if }x<0\\\frac1{x+1}&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$$
and is not *always* decreasing: for example, $g(-1) = -1$ and $g(0)=1$.